# Download page not found

Tags: downloads

I tried to download the ubuntu desktop version.But it is not downloading and showing an error message that 'The requested URL /20.04.1/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso was not found on this server'. Please help me to download the ubuntu software.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to download from? A little more information might help.

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading it from main server.

Go to this page → https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.1/, click on Desktop image-- it will bring you to direct download link of Ubuntu 20.04 latest releases.

[image]

Otherwise you can click [this](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.1/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)

Comment: BTW, it says AMD64. Shal I presume it goes good for Intel as well? Mine is Intel Core i5.

Comment: `amd64` implies 64 bit architecture, it should work on modern processor like i5

Comment: Thanks, that was a quick call.